# Topology: Clopen Sets

Tags: general-topology

I got the following question and solution from somewhere else.  Now, I understand why the set $[0,1)$ is clopen but I don't understand the solutions reasoning.  Is there some theorem that says the intersection of an open (closed) set with **any** set is always open (closed)?

Question:

Consider $X=[0,2]\setminus{1}$ as a subspace of the real line $\mathbb{R}$.  Show that the subset $[0,1)\subset X$ is both open and closed.

Answer:

$[0,1)=(-\infty,1)\cap X$.  Since $(-\infty,1)$ is open $[0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

$[0,1)=[0,1]\cap X$.  Since $[0,1]$ is closed $[0,1)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There is the definition of subspace topology on $X\subset M$ that states that a set is open in $X$ iff it is the intersection of $X$ and an open set in $M$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get for reading top-down. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such theorem, because it's false. What's going on in the solution is the definition of the subspace topology:

> Given a topological space $(A, \tau)$ and a subset $X\subseteq A$, the *subspace topology on $X$* is the topology given by open sets in $A$ intersected with $X$: $(X, \{U\cap X: U\in\tau\})$.

That is, a set $Y\subseteq X$ is open *in the sense of $X$* if $Y=X\cap U$ for some $U$ which is open *in the sense of $A$*. Similarly, we can prove that a set $Y\subseteq X$ is closed *in the sense of $X$* if $Y=X\cap C$ for some $C$ which is closed *in the sense of $A$*.